# Is there any way to avoid missing bytes on a Python socket data transmission?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets

I have two different python clients communicating with each other (Client A and Client B) through an external node server on the internet. Client A should send many identified messages in a short period of time to client B, where the node server is responsible to forward all received messages from A to B.

What is happening is that client A is overwriting some message.

I have detected the problem on client B, which is where I analyze the messages. However, the problem occurs in the transmission of messages between client A and Node server, because I am already able to see the broken message on node server logs.

I will show some pseudo-code along with some logs regarding the error (Client A and Server only) :

**Client A**

Code
    ...
    import socket

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))

...

while not END:
    #Prepare message_to_clinet

    #If I uncomment this timer, the error will not appear (or appear later)
    #time.sleep(0.2)

    # I have tried either sendall and send. But it seems that is not effective
    server_socket.sendall(message_to_client)
    print '(Sent):' + message_to_client
```

Logs when the error occurs
Imagine that I want to send 100 times the message: 'Where is the bug?'

```
...
(Sent): Where is the bug?
(Sent): Where is the bug?
(Sent): Where is the bug?
(Sent): Where is the bug?
(Sent): Where is the bug?
...
```

**Node**

Code

```
const net = require('net');
const tcpServer = net.createServer(connection.requestHandler);
tcpServer.listen(connection.port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('tcp socket error', err);
    }

    console.log(`tcp socket listening on ${connection.port}`);
});

...

const requestHandler = (sock) => {   
    sock.on('data', (data) => {
        const protocol_message = new Buffer(data).toString('ascii');

        //Send this message to remote client
        currentConnection.sendMessagesToClient(protocol_message)
        console.log('Received: ' + protocol_message)
    }
}
```

Logs when the error occurs.
I receive more messages for each socket.send maybe because socket.send it is called several times in a short time on client A (which is not a problem because on the real code I have a 4 byte-length prefix to prevent errors when reading on clinet B)

```
...
Received: Where is the bug? Where is the bug? Where is the bug?  Where is the bug?Where is the bug?
Received: Where is the bug? Where is the bug? Where is the bug?  Where is the bug?Where is the bug?
Received: Where is thWhere is the bug? Where is the bug?Where is the bug?
...
```

Here I can see that one of the 100 messages I repeatedly sent is broken. However, on client A, everything is apparently well.

Does anyone know what is a possible cause of this error?

I know if put a time.sleep(0.1) between each message on client A, the error takes more time and transmitted bytes to happen. But when it works, it is just too slow. 
I also know that if I use the developer local server, I cannot reproduce the error. My guess is that this is related to socket buffer and delay on transmission.

EDIT: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: This kind of problem sometimes occurs because of a multithreaded/multiprocess server. One server/process begins to read part of the stream and stops reading for processing its input. In the meanwhile, another process/thread has read something on the same stream and things are out of sync. Fix: never allow more than one thread on a single stream. Only posted as a comment because it is just a wild guess...

Comment: I guess it is something like that. But I am not sure if I have control on the node server side to control whether create or not a thread to read the incoming data. But i agree with you that the problem might be server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. Basically, everything was correct with python clients. However, with TCP sockets, messages can be split in chunks on an upper layer, which leads to a stupid bug on the server side because I was looking for the first character to decide to which socket I'll redirect the message. Of course, this is not a good approach at all, and now it is solved and working.

Although it was a bug on the server side, I only found it because I did some research and conclude that TCP guarantees the same order but it can split in chunks the data.

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could always try:

```py
s.recv #insert increased buffer size here#
```

Might work.

Comment: I cannot do that because the node server which receives the messages, does not have that option.

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves so what do you use to receive messages then?

Comment: On the node code, I've shown how I created the server: net.createServer(connection.requestHandler); Then, every time I send data from python client to node server with socket.send, node run this kind of interruption sock.on('data', (data)). However, on a pratical scenario, when sending a stream of data, on this interrupt i have access to more data than the available data on a single socket.send from python client. And i dont have control of the amount of data i want to read.

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves how about
```python
clients=[]
...
clients.append(client)
for Client in clients:
    Client.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late reply, but hope it helps someone:

This problem occurs due to the high processing speed in the server compared to the transmission rate over the socket.

I got the same problem when using s.recv(MSG_SIZE) without telling the function to wait until getting the MSG_SIZE I've set.

Using s.recv(MSG_SIZE, socket.MSG_WAITALL) instead of s.recv(MSG_SIZE) will fix this problem.